# Problems with powerline disturbing wifi signal

Tags: networking, powerline-networking

In 2017 we bought some powerline adapters to get our network to the attic because the main router is 2 floors down and we wanted to have a server. 
This was working until last year December.

Last year we noticed that our laptops started losing the wifi signal. Sometimes the laptop would say connected but it wasn't. I thought oh well time for new router from our ISP. They send us one and we replaced it. Still the same problem. We disbaled the wifi on the powerline adapter but no effect. When we unlugged them our issues were solved.

So I thought well the powerline adapters are broken so I bought two new adapters. Installed them and tested and still the same problems.

I disabled the 5.0Ghz wifi signal on the router, changed the DNS to 8.8.8.8 (Google), disabled wifi on the adapters but nothing worked.

Does anyone have a solution or explanation for this? 
The last weird thing is that only the windows machines were affected. My dad runs linux and the mobile devives all run android and they didn't have a problem.